What is the smallest area of a central section of the unit hypercube?
Let $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ denote the unit hypercube i.e. $\mathcal{U} = [0,1]^n$, and assume that for some $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one denotes by
$$
\mathcal{H} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | d^T\cdot \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1_{n \times 1}\right) = 0  \right\}
$$ a hyperplane passing through the center of the hyper-cube. I am interested in the minimum area of $\mathcal{H} \cap \mathcal{U}$. I know from literature that the maximum area of a general intersection between a hyperplane and the unit hypercube is $\sqrt{2}$ see here.
However, my question is about the smallest area of a hyperplane which is restricted to contain the center of the unit hypercube. I somehow think that this is 1 ( one ). Any section parallel with the faces, as well as some rotations of it, generates a section area of 1 ( one ) or greater, but I cannot prove the general case!

Doesn’t Theorem 2 on page 437 (or page 3 inside the article) in your linked literature answer your question?

@X-Rui thank you alot for pointing that out! I have not read the paper, but merely relied on the abstract for the info regarding the mentioned results! My bad! Now that I had a look at it, it seems that the proof uses probabilistic techniques ... Am I wright? To be honest I have always felt a little uneasy about probabilistic results when it comes to algorithms design (where I want to use this actually), as these (probabilistic results) are not bothered by a countable number of counterexamples ...

@X-Rui if you post this as an answer I will accept it!
